# How to replace a line in a set of files in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

im dealing with this:

```
for listout in glob.glob("*.out"):

    lst.append(listout)

    replaceprocess= "find -name '*.out' | xargs perl -pi -e 's/CARTESIAN COORDINATES/CARTESIAN COORDINATES\n\n     NO.       ATOM         X         Y         Z /'"

    os.system(replaceprocess)
```

but the problem is that it replaces each line-file lots of times(and not only once, as i need), any solution?

PS: First time im asking

Comment: The shell command performs the task you are asking about.  It is unclear what you hope for the Python code to accomplish in addition.  Just remove Python and you're done.

Comment: The immediate problem is that `find` will find all the matching files so the `for` loop is completely redundant.  Alternatively, lose the `find` and pass the matching files to Perl directly.  Again, no `for` loop required.  But doing this in Python entirely is obviously more elegant and robust.

Comment: @tripleee hey, i cant ask anymore, i can't understand why. I don't have too bad questions, neither with down votes..

Comment: I don't see anything immediately alarming on your profile.  Maybe ask on [meta].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple Python script to replace text in a set of files.

```
import glob, fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob("*.out"), inplace=True):
    print(line.replace('CARTESIAN COORDINATES', 'CARTESIAN COORDINATES\n\n     NO.       ATOM         X         Y         Z '))
```